# Linq: Select 1st item from other group

Tags: linq

I am trying to write a query to find just one item from the group, where they grouped by Industry and Weight, then from this one I have to get where Weight is Max and Balance is Max too
This is the example:

```
var data = new[] {
new {ID = 1, Industry = 2, Weight = 2, Balance = 500}, 
new {ID = 2, Industry = 2, Weight = 2, Balance = 300}, 
new {ID = 3, Industry = 2, Weight = 1, Balance = 100},
new {ID = 5, Industry = 4, Weight = 1, Balance = 100}, 
new {ID = 6, Industry = 4, Weight = 2, Balance = 150}, 
new {ID = 7, Industry = 4, Weight = 1, Balance = 300},
};

var res = from a in data group a by new {a.Industry, a.Weight} into g
let ID = g.First().ID
let Balance = g.Max(a => a.Balance)
select new { ID, g.Key.Industry, g.Key.Weight, Balance};
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

So as the result I should get just two records

```
ID   Industry   Weight   Balance
1      2           2      500
6      4           2      150
```

but with query above I got 4 records
Any advice?

Regards,
Dmitriy

Comment: How are you going to get ID 4? It doesn't even exist. And you will get 4 records because there are 4 combinations of Industry and Weight.

Comment: sorry, yes. The second item should be
Id = 6, Industry = 4, Weight = 2, Balance = 150

Comment: You're misunderstanding how the groupings work.  You are grouping by two fields.  Given the data, there are four distinct combinations of those two fields so you're going to get four groups back (hence the four records).  Albin shows how you can obtain those two desired records.  Otherwise how you're explaining it, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many different solutions, but one would be to only group by Industry and sort each group according to your "first element to pick" criteria and then pick the first item in each group.

```
var res = from item in data
    group item by item.Industry into g
    let first = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Weight)
                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.Balance).First()
    select first;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.GroupBy(x=>new {x.Industry,x.Weight})
    .ToDictionary(y=>y.Key,y=>y.ToList().Max(x=>x.Balance));
```

If you dont want a dictionary then you can as well Select a new DTO or a dynamic object as follows:

```
data.GroupBy(x=>new {x.Industry,x.Weight})
    .Select(x=>new {x.Key.Industry,x.Key.Weight,x.ToList().Max(y=>y.Balance)});
```

Hopefully that is what you need.

Comment: Thank you! but it returned 4 items, but I need just two

Comment: It is bound to return 4 as discussed in the question comments.. if you want only 2 use Take(2) ??